# Is <object> old fashioned?

Tags: html, object, tags

Something like below,which is complicated to figure out what it exactly means:

```
9.<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="945" height="102">  
10.  
11.    <param name="movie" value="66.swf" />  
12.  
13.    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />  
14.  
15.    <EMBED height="60" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="66.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="468" wmode="transparent" quality="high"></EMBED>    
16.  
17.</object>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and stop worrying about it. Let the library handle the flash embedding.

Various browsers require various embedding techniques for various reasons, and we as application developers shouldn't need to worry about the arbitrary details.

Answer (score 1):

`<object>` isn't really old-fashoned, however using all-caps for tags like the `<EMBED>` you've got there *is*.  It isn't valid XML, or valid XHTML for that matter.  (Then again, doing object/embeds for flash causes validation errors with the W3C XHTML Strict validator anyway... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you call things like youtube old fashioned, then yes.

[Try here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)