# <embed> tag not working for mozila firefox 4.0 but work in IE

Tags: php

I'm trying to open pdf file in browser but not in mozilla .But the same file open in google chrome and IE .i am using following code to execute pdf file in browser.

```
<embed src="admin/images/pdf_file/<?php echo $scheme_desc; ?>#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1" width="100%" height="450"></embed>
```

Comment: Your current words mean that your goal is to open a pdf file in any browser BUT Mozilla. I suspect you mean more that your code **works** for all except Mozilla? If I'm right, you might want to change that into something like `but it's not working in Mozilla`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object

Comment: Are you using Firefox on Mac? If so, see this: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/05/04/adobe-reader-blocked-mac/

Answer (score 0):

This this code:

```
<object type="MIME type of your file" data="your file here" width="100%" height="450"></object>
```

Comment: try this code its working for me:<object type="MIME type of your file" data="your file here" width="100%" height="450"></object>