# Differences between the HTML tags of embed, object, and video?

Tags: html, object, video, embed

What are the technical differences between those three tags and why would someone use one over the other? In HTML 4 why did embed fall out of favor and have object replace it, only to come back into favor in HTML 5 and object being left behind? Is it true that the wmv format doesn't work with the video tag?

Comment: Have you researched this at all?

Comment: embed vs object subset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/02/22/html-object-and-embed-tags/

As for the video tag, WMVs wont always work because if you're on a Mac you would have to install a plugin

Comment: that link is dead

Comment: thats why links are always discouraged on here