# can't postMessage to <object>, but it CAN recieve messages

Tags: javascript, postmessage, object-tag

I'm loading a website from another domain into an object-tag and and try to post messages to it but I can't get it to work.

So I tried using a popupwindow and an iframe instead, and both methods worked.

But I think it **should** work with object-tag to, because if I don't filter for origin I get other messages (messages which I haven't sent)

Comment: maybe this is a non issue since it did work with Iframe, but oh well

Comment: why should it work? if you view this stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements might help you better understand what the use case for it is