# HTML Object bottom-clipped, cut off on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

```html
<div data-role="page" id="samples">
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><a href="#ceremony" data-icon="back">Back</a><h1>Ceremony Planner 2.0 - Samples</h1></div>
 <object type="text/html" data="http://www.thereverendmichael.com/ceremony-samples"></object>
</div>
```

The object scrolls and works fine on all browsers but will not scroll on mobile, it gets cut off and bottom-clipped. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Why you don't use `<iframe>` instead `<object>`? I tihnk it's the best option here. Have you try? Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21115112/4703082) to see the differencies between `<iframe>`, `<object>` and `<embed`> tags. Maybe helps you.

Comment: I've also tried `<iframe>` and it resulted in the same bottom-clipping.

Comment: And Have you put the viewport inside `<head>`? `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Yes I have made sure to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- First: Make you sure that you put the viewport inside `<head>` like
  `<head><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>`
- Use `<iframe>` instead `<object>`
- Add a wrapper to the `<iframe>`and add the following style

html

```
<div class="wrap">
    <iframe src="http://www.thereverendmichael.com/ceremony-samples"></iframe>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap {
    // -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; Non-standard! 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

SOURCE: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

If it doesn't work uncomment the other style although I see the documentation and is not recommended to use it [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling).

However here is working: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe you can see 
the style that applies to `#iframewrapper` watching the `view-source` (`ctrl+u` in your browser) and looking for `#iframewrapper`

Hope this helped you!