# How to load `google map` to `div` directly to container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I require to load a map to my page. I have the URL for that which is :

`https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en`

if I paste the above url, I am getting the map loaded in the browser.
Same way I am trying to load this map in to my web page. But nothing loads..

what is the correct way to load the above map in to my web page?

Here is my try:

```
$(function(){

  var mapURL = "https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en";

  $("#map").load(mapURL);

});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bg65OSEcFy1vgddML8Xp?p=preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Url` is not directly load on div .So you can append `iframe` on div like this to load map.

```js
$(function() {
  var html = '<iframe src="https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en"></iframe>';
  $("#map").append(html);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'><map>
<div id='map1'><map>
```

Or If you don't want to use `iframe` you cane use `embed`  tag.

```js
var html='<embed src="https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en" width=200 height=200 />';
 $("#map").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

### You can trigger DIV load Event

> [HTML iframe Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

The  tag specifies an inline frame.

An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

```js
$(function(){
 $('div[onload]').trigger('onload');
});


function  displayMap() {
  var mapURL = "https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en";
   
 $("#map").append("<iframe src=" + mapURL +"></iframe>"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onload="displayMap()" id ="map"></div>
```

**You can display your map without iframe**

> [HTML object Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

The  tag defines an embedded object within an HTML document. Use this element to embed multimedia (like audio, video, Java applets, ActiveX, PDF, and Flash) in your web pages.

```html
<div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en" width="800px" height="300px" style="overflow:auto;border:1px solid">
    </object>
</div>
```

[Difference between  and  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements)

Comment: What is diff between `object` and `iframe`-?

Comment: @user2024080, check it here for the differences between iframe, object and embed: http://bencreasy.com/object-versus-embed/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(window).on('load', function(){          
    var mapURL = "https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en";          
    $("#map").html('<iframe src="'+mapURL+'" height="450" width="600"></iframe>');          
});
```

OR

```
$(window).on('load', function(){          
    var mapURL = "https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en";          
    $("#map").html('<object data="'+mapURL+'" width="600" height="450" type="text/html">Loading Map</object>');          
});
```

OR

```
$(window).on('load', function(){          
    var mapURL = "https://servicepoints.dhlecommerce.com/?lnglat=3.16327,101.69507&language=en";
    $("#map").html('<embed id="map" src="'+mapURL+'" width=600 height=450 />');          
});
```

Comment: Can't I load without Iframe..? can you update my plunkr?