# Iframe embedded video not showing on frontend in moodle LMS

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I have been trying to figure out a way to solve this issue over two weeks now. I have developed a moodle system and idea is to show youtube videos to teach and train users on the platform. The issue is youtube or vimeo video iframe embed do not show on the frontend but shows in the admin backend editor. Have tried all available solution in moodle community but nothing seems to work. Will be very happy someone have a solution for me. Thanks

Comment: Is the video embed http or https? If you are behind an SSL connection, a http source won't appear. (There's a HTTPS conversion tool in moodle: admin-security-http security to fix embeds). Also check admin option allowobjectembed is set to yes, and while it's not advised, check the enabletrusttext setting to see if that makes a difference.

The other option is to use Moodle's own media plugin.

Comment: @AlanKaelBall the embed is a youtube video and it https i have enable allow embed object install ssl on my hosting and used the conversion tool but still it does no show. On checking the html element i think moodle automatically sensitize iframe tag and convert them to p tag. If any other solution is available i will be glad to know project deadline is near

Answer (score 0):

[There's More than One Way to Play Embedded YouTube Videos](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/theres-more-than-one-way-to-play-embedded-youtube-videos.html)

You can go old-school using `<object>` or `<embed>` (which often works best when `<iframe>` is causing problems).

See also> [difference between iframe, embed and object elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements)