# How to embed a website in my site's blog?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a site with a blog and using an embed code:

`<embed src="https://www.timeout.com/london/things-to-do/the-best-life-drawing-classes-in-london" style="width:500px; height: 300px;"</embed>`

This works fine. But when I try:

`<embed src="http://anyamountofbooks.com" style="width:500px; height: 300px;"</embed>`

It doesn't work.

The site exists but, when I view the page on my blog, it says, 'this site may be down.

Comment: Have you tried using an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?

Comment: Yeah. It came out kinda weird...

Comment: But perhaps it was the wrong code. Do you have an example?

Comment: iframe will do.

Comment: Iframe doesn't work and totally messes up my site.... https://Adsler.co.uk/adsler-blog

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'll want to use an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) instead of [`<embed>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) to display HTML content. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements) for some more in depth analysis. Now to the root of your problem.

If you're embedding external content into your site (such as by iframe/embed), you'll need to make sure that the protocols match:

- An **http://** website can embed both **http://** and **https://** content.
- An **https://** website can ONLY embed **https://** content.

The http://anyamountofbooks.com website doesn't appear to have a valid SSL certificate, so you won't be able to frame it if your website is secured and accessed through **https://**.

The other thing to consider is that some websites don't allow themselves to be embedded, [here's on article](https://ziplineinteractive.com/blog/how-to-prevent-a-website-from-being-loaded-in-an-iframe/) on a couple ways to do it. The website you're trying to embed may employ one of those practices to prevent itself from being embedded.

Comment: Which means im bu%@£&£(.. then? No way around it?

Comment: There is just one thing. If your theory is right, how come i can embed http://londondrawing.com in my site successfully using `<embed>? See here..... https://adsler.co.uk/adsler-blog/

Comment: Also, I tried tried i frame, didn't work.... See here https://adsler.co.uk/adsler-blog

Comment: So there is really is no logical reason why <embed> doesn't work with http://www.anyamountofbooks.com when it works with http://londondrawing.com

Comment: https://tbwdrawingprize.artopps.co.uk/online-entry/
This site embeds itself even without <embed>

Comment: So it seems totally random what will embed and what won't. I'm using WordPress and know from past experience that Utube embeds just by copying and pasting link...

Comment: It won't even embed <embed src="https://google.com"style="width:500px; height: 300px;"</embed>