# Include interactive plot in html format in Github page

Tags: github, include, markdown, github-pages

I'm trying to post my first post in github page (Index.md). I'd like to publish a interactive highchartin `html` format. Here is the interactive highchart: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/761497_2be5b28bcb2a45a28aac7b0e99cb9b07.html

I've tried use `<iframe src="https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/761497_2be5b28bcb2a45a28aac7b0e99cb9b07.html" frameborder="0" height="400" width="430"></iframe>`, without sucess.

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: What's `fig1.html`? You probably want to link directly to an image, e.g. `<img src="some_jpg.jpg">`.

Comment: `fig1.html`is the image present in "https://rpubs.com/guiaguilar/testtreeemap "

Comment: I don't see any images there. There's an interactive highchart...

Comment: you need to have a ***direct*** link to the image you're trying to embed. You can't put a webpage containing an image in an `<img>` tag. If you want to render the actual page though, you might want to look into [embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements) it.