# Dialog element from file

Tags: html, jquery

I've been reading with interest about the dialog element in HTML:

```
  <dialog id="helpOnName">
    <p>
     The name is arbitrary. There is no validation, whatsoever.
    </p>
  </dialog>
```

So, that's well for this simple text. However, with growing complexity, I'd rather have something like

```
  <dialog url="helpOnName.html"></dialog>
```

In other words: Rather than embedding the dialog contents into the opening page, I'd like it to be read from another file.

Is that possible? How? (Using JQuery would be fine.)

Answer (score 2):

You may have different options to achieve the goal to have content loaded from an external resource.

- Doing an ajax request that will return a response to embed
  dynamically in the dialog
- Embedding the content inside an `<iframe>` tag
- Referencing the content with an `<object>` tag

This is the demo for the third and most original option of those.

The content for the `<dialog>` is specified by an `<object>` element fed by an url having its content. As a fallback, I added the option that will override its content with a default template defined in the page itself.

**<object>: The External Object element**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

**:scope** (worth of mention)

*for selecting only starting from the direct children

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope

This is an answer better covering `<iframe>` `<embed>` `<object>`

[Difference between iframe, embed and object elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements)

And I would add I forgot to mention `<link>`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  const dialog = document.getElementById('primaryDialog');
  fillDialogContent(dialog);
})

function fillDialogContent(dialog){  
  const template = dialog.querySelector(':scope > .fallback');  
  const content = template.content.cloneNode(true);  
  const objectEl = dialog.querySelector('object');  
  objectEl.append(content); 
}
```

```html
<dialog id="primaryDialog" open>
    <object data="your-custom-dialog-content.html" type="text/html"></object>
    
    <template class="fallback">
      <div class="container">
        <p>This is the default dialog content</p>
        <p>An error occurred in the attempt to load the custom template</p>
      </div>
    </template>
    
</dialog>
```

Comment: Been web coding for 25 years and I thought objects were dead after Flash. Cool trick. But the iframe is the simplest way, eh?

Comment: yes it's a very very old idea long gone .. and the reason why I decided to adopt it for this answer was because I was afraid to involve added constraints due to iframe isolation and security engaged. I gave for granted that the object element was not going to be as that strict. But to be fair I didn't test if the content loaded from external asset was going to work. By the way I added the mdn page now for the sake of giving it some legitimacy

Comment: I didn't stress it out but this part was the most interesting `.querySelector(':scope > .fallback');` that just limits the query to the ***direct*** children using the `:scope` pseudo-class

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it with `fetch()`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(ev) {
  document.querySelectorAll("[data-url]").forEach(el=>
   fetch(el.dataset.url).then(r=>r.text()).then(html=>el.innerHTML=html)
  )
});
```

```html
<h3>First dialogue</h3>
<div data-url="https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&format=html">hello</div>
<h3>Second dialogue</h3>
<div data-url="https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=5&make-it-spicy=1&format=html">hello again</div>
```

Comment: Reminder that this won't work if you have [hardened CSP policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) in place, which you should since they prevent XSS.

Comment: @RuanMendes this is a valid point to be aware of!
However, assuming the OP wants to include text files containing HTML markup from the same (their own) site, strict CSP policies should not be a critical issue here.

Comment: If there are no scripts in that same-site HTML, that is correct. My main point is that to do this, they should understand what CSP is. `iframe`s would be a simpler way.

Comment: Point taken. However, DOM elements contained in `iframes` cannot be addressed in the same way as other DOM elements from the embedding document. This might make it a little bit harder to supply JavaScript based methods (rooted in the embedding document) for augmenting the actual dialogue logic.