# Passing Variables from HTML to Flash ActionScript 3.0 

Tags: html, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I just want to pass some parameters to  ActionScript 3.0 from HTML.
When I search for it I see that I can use  I CAN USE  [ flashvars ]

```
 <param name="flashvars" value="serverUrl=rtmp://X.X.X.X/live&streamName=Camera.stream">
```

And can  access those paramters from  AS3 :

```
var serverUrl : String =  root.loaderInfo.parameters.serverUrl;
var serverStreamName : String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.serverStreamName;
```

But when I try this, I see that serverUrl and   serverStreamName are null:

```
var txt:TextField = new TextField(); 
txt.text =" URL: " + serverUrl ;
addChild(txt)
```

**What I am doing wrong? Any idea?**

Note:

My HTML which call SWF file:

```
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="..."....>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="CustomVideoPlayer.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="serverUrl=rtmp://X.X.X.X/live&streamName=Camera.stream">
    <param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />   
    <embed src="CustomVideoPlayer.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="400" name="CustomVideoPlayer" ...>
    </object>
</noscript>
```

And try to reach those paramters from AS3 like this:

```
var serverUrl : String =  root.loaderInfo.parameters.serverUrl;
var serverStreamName : String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.serverStreamName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that could cause the parameters to be missing, being null, is if you haven't specified `flashvars` also in the `<embed>` tag.

The `<param>` tag is used together with the `<object>` tag, and is read by browsers that render/execute the `<object>` tag, but not by the browsers that instead use the `<embed>` tag. The `<embed>` tag in your example is shortened, as is mine here, so maybe you already have it, but you would need to include the `flashvars` there also, like:

```
<embed src="CustomVideoPlayer.swf" flashvars="serverUrl=rtmp://X.X.X.X/live&streamName=Camera.stream" ...>
```

In other words, you need to include the flashvars twice, once for `<object>` and once for `<embed>`, as with other things such as `allowFullScreen`.

Comment: Well, the problem was at Flash CS4 generated HTML...I coded html manuely...So I can access parameters...

Comment: Good. And as loxxy says in his answer, I would normally and in general recommend using swfobject rather than doing the object/embed html manually.

Answer (score 2):

I would have commented to use object tag instead of embed, [EMBED vs. OBJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)

But now with all the support for embed by HTML5, I'm unsure.

Whatever be the case, I would always, prefer using using a popular library like [swfobjecct](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), simply for the sake of convenience & being on the safe side.

With that being said, this is how you do it with swfobject & Javascript :

```
 var flashVars = {};
 flashVars.parameter1 = "abc";
 flashVars.parameter2 = "bbc";    

 swfobject.embedSWF("myMovie.swf", "myDIV", "720", "600", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashVars, {}, {}, swfLoadComplete);
```