# Embedding SWF file in HTML5 - How to add alternative content?

Tags: html, flash

I'd like to embed an SWF file in HTML5. It works fine with this code:

`<embed src="main.swf" width="550" height="400" />`

But how could I show alternative content (an animated GIF image, or a static JPEG or PNG) just in cases which swf file is not supported (and still validating in w3! ;) )

Thank you!

Comment: Use an `<object>` tag instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the object tag instead of the embed tag like so: 
`<object width="550" height="400" data="main.swf">Alertnative Content Here</object>`

See: [EMBED vs. OBJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)

Comment: Thank YOU!!! It worked perfectly. I've just had to use <param name=FlashVars value="" /> for pass the flashvars values and use data instead of src. It works perfectly! THANK YOU!!!