# Embed PDF at full height

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question ... is it possible to embed a PDF in a HTML document where the height is always 100%. The problem is the actual height of the pdf could vary and the layout needs to respond to this.

Comment: How are you embedding the pdf document?

Answer (score 22):

There are several ways to embed PDF in HTML.

One would be to use [PDFObject](http://www.pdfobject.com). The below example works out of the box in firefox, you'll find further instructions for most browsers on their website.

```
<object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
    No biggie... you can <a href="myfile.pdf">click here to
    download the PDF file.</a></p>
</object>
```

Or you could use the google drive viewer to display any PDF (and quite a few more file types):

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[http://PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE.pdf]&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Using the drive viewer your visitors don't need any additional software/plugin to view the files.

You can then adjust the height of the PDF container with css. i.e

```
#yourcontainer { height: 100vh; }
```

Comment: I can get this method to use the full height. Anyone got it working? Otherwise great respons!

Comment: @cholewa1992 You mean "I can't get this method to use full height"?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo yes, sorry. That was what I ment

Comment: @cholewa1992 add this to the page's css: html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

Answer (score 20):

None of the above answers worked for me.
The following worked across every platform I needed it to (ie, I didn't test IE).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    <object data="pdf.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="min-height:100vh;width:100%"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how did you make this so easy where everything else is not - thank you

Comment: update body to `<body style="margin:0">` to removet he annoying margin

Answer (score 5):

You must to set width\height a container

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
<embed id="frPDF" height="100%" width="100%" src="http://eurecaproject.eu/files/5013/9885/7113/example4.pdf"></embed>
</div>
```

---

[Look example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6ma75wj/3/)

Comment: Thank you this helped. I am using a library openHtmlToPdf, it was not considering image tag's height or css height attribute. Finaly your solution helped. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;            /* Reset default margin */
}

iframe {
    display: block;       /* iframes are inline by default */
    background: #000;
    border: none;         /* Reset default border */
    height: 100vh;        /* Viewport-relative units */
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[http://PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE.pdf]&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `<object>` - [EMBED vs. OBJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)

```
<object data="file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't strictly true with HTML5 - the `<embed />` tag is part of [the official standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element).

Answer (score 0):

I like the functionality that comes with the html objects for PDFs as opposed to some libraries like PDF.js for light projects. This is definitely not the best answer but I'm currently using JQuery with Bootstrap in an Angular 6 app so I modify height after the the view loads.

I set

```
        <object id="pdf" data="path.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%"></object>
```

then in my component I adjust the height based on the ratio of the width to height.
For example, an 8 x 11.5 document would give the height 1.4375 x the width.

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var width = $("#pdf").width();
    $("#pdf").prop("height", width * 1.4375 + "px");
   }
```

Saw this post and figured I would post. Hope this helps and please correct me if you think this is bad coding practices.