# How to get embedded object to take up the whole height of the container div?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angular2/4 and angular-material (https://material.angular.io/) and I want to stick a PDF in it. The problem is, the height of the pdf object apepars to be small and does not fill the whole space of the container. I can manually attach a style="500px" to have the height be 500px, but if I just do a height of 100%, then the height is messed up. Width is fine with 100%.

How do I get my pdf object to fill up the entire height of the container?

```
<md-tab-group>
<md-tab label="Tab 1">
    <object data="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
   <p><b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
</object>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Contents of Tab 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the way CSS works in that height only wraps your content and doesn't automatically scale to 100% the way width does?  The problem is probably a result of a parent element or elements not having a set height.

Comment: This means that setting the height to 100% means filling 100% of the parent element's height not showing 100% of the content.

Comment: Then how do I get it to fill? My parents element is also set to 100%, which does not help at all... is this not possible? Does javascript have to be thrown in the mix?

Comment: It needs to go all the way up the parent chain to include the body as well.  The body element not being set to 100% or a specific value is usually the cause of relative height problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed PDF at full height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25766131/5283213)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can try to use CSS `calc()` function with `vh` (view height) units:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">
    <object data="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2" 
            type="application/pdf" 
            style="height:calc(100vh - 70px)"
            width="100%">
      <p>
        <b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. 
        Please download the PDF to view it: 
        <a href="/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf">Download PDF</a>.
      </p>
    </object>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Contents of Tab 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I used here `style="height:calc(100vh - 70px)"` with 70px compensation for md tab headers and plunker headers.

If you want your code to be fully automated, you can calculate this compensation value in `ngAfterViewInit` hook of your component, using [Renderer2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html) or [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) classes, and then use it within `ngStyle` directive in your HTML

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/LRscYr4A13HEjWAmCNo9?p=preview