# PDF file is not opening in <embed> tag in chrome

Tags: html

PDF file is not opening in `<embed>` tag  in chrome:

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com/pdf/100008156325455.pdf" width="510" height="432"/>
```

This is not working in Google chrome.
Is there is any way to show PDF file for review in all browsers?

Comment: Use `iframe` and set `src` attribute as PDF path

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object

Answer (score 2):

Use iframe instead of embed.

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/pdf/100008156325455.pdf" width="510" height="432"/>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/L07jL7ca/1/)

Comment: I have also use iframe but it is also not working.Please help me.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh It may be a cache problem. Clear your history in a Chrome and Try again