# How To Use The Browser To Show ppt / doc / xls / pdf In Firefox /IE /Chrome

Tags: html, pdf, powerpoint, doc

On my Html tag , I have one URL (http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf) that wants to open it on browser without download how can I do it , please help me to do this issue?

> PS: I have found out the solution with Google API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked for a great and easy way to show *.PPT / *.PDF / *.XLS / *.DOC in Browser, hopefully this method can help everyone who has the same problem like me as following sample code

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://download.ppt-to-dvd.com/tem/wedding2.potx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.ysnp.gov.tw/upload/%E4%B8%AD%E8%8B%B1%E8%A9%9E%E5%BD%99%E5%B0%8D%E7%85%A7%E8%A1%A8.doc&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

hi you can use object element for showing pdf,doc etc. like

```
<object data="xx.pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="xx.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

for more info check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)