# How can open document in web browser using Iframe in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have requirement like open any document in web browser. I am using WEBAPI for getting document details(byte Format).I am able to download .but I want to open in browser using IFRAME  in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: hi check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)

Comment: Hi Shalish.I am getting response as binary data form DataBase.it is dynamic.how can get the URL of this binary data?

Comment: `var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var Url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(binary_data);`

Comment: is this client side code ?

Answer (score 1):

As to the base requirement, this is really straight-forward, and it sounds like you're mostly there. The only problem is you can't simply set an iframe to some blob of data. Think of the iframe as another browser window; it just happens to be embedded within a web page. You have to set the iframe to a URL that it should load. As a result, all you need is some action in your MVC project that consumes your Web Api and returns the document as a response. Then you just set your iframe to load the URL that routes to that action.

However, there's a huge caveat: a web browser can't just load a random document. Web browsers parse HTML. That's it. Anything else needs a plugin. Some browsers, like Chrome, include support for some file types, like PDFs, out of the box. Others need plugins manually installed. It's generally a safe bet that PDF will supported for inline viewing in most browsers due to its prevalence online. (If the user's browser doesn't support it out of the box, there's a high likelihood that the user would have installed a PDF viewer plugin at some point to add support). If you're talking about a Word document or such, you're mostly out of luck, though.

Comment: Thanks Chris, how can make binary data of any document to URL.So that i can give that URL to IFRAME.

Comment: Return `File` with byte array rather than the traditional `View` from your action.

Answer (score 1):

```
<embed style="width:100%; height:1300px; " src="~/PDF/Arma3Lau.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
```

Thats the way to display pdf-files