# Using an IF statement within a FOREACH loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to execute the following code but it's not working:

```
<?php foreach($reciepts as $value) { 
    $extension = get_file_extension($value);
    if($extension == "pdf") { ?>
        <p>Receipt:</p><br><embed src="<?php echo $value; ?>">
    <?php }
    else { ?>
        <p>Receipt:</p><br><img style="max-width:500px; max-height:500px;" src="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
```

The `$reciepts` array iin this case is:

```
[7] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://coppermountain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/12-c07945f2e8e37e124bd5be2c8a979300/2016/02/Screen-Shot-2016-02-01-at-09.33.18.png
                [1] => http://coppermountain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/12-c07945f2e8e37e124bd5be2c8a979300/2016/02/Expenses-1.pdf
            )
```

The function to get the file extension:

```
function get_file_extension($value) {
    return substr(strrchr($value,'.'),1);
}
```

The tests I have run so far:

```
$extension = $form_data['field'][7][1];
echo get_file_extension($extension);
```

`$extension` echoes out `pdf` as expected

Also the loop works fine if I don't include the IF/ELSE statement as below:

```
<?php foreach($reciepts as $value) { ?>
    <p>Receipt:</p><br><img style="max-width:500px; max-height:500px;" src="<?php echo $value; ?>" /> 
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe a bit better what isn't working precisely ? Thanks

Comment: you sure that `$reciepts` isn't spelled as `$receipts`? which should be spelled that way. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Why aren't you using pathinfo() to get the extension?

Comment: Note that `<embed>` has had a lot of troubles displaying PDF. Perhaps try the suggestions in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object).

Comment: @P.Gearman     I had never heard of it before. Is there an advantage to using it?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. It is designed to retrieve path information, including the extension.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a close brace of your foreach loop, the following works.

```
<?php
function get_file_extension($value)
{
    return substr(strrchr($value, '.'), 1);
}

$reciepts = [
    'http://coppermountain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/12-c07945f2e8e37e124bd5be2c8a979300/2016/02/Screen-Shot-2016-02-01-at-09.33.18.png',
    'http://coppermountain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/12-c07945f2e8e37e124bd5be2c8a979300/2016/02/Expenses-1.pdf'
];
foreach ($reciepts as $value) {
    $extension = get_file_extension($value);
    if ($extension == "pdf") {
        ?>
        <p>Receipt:</p><br><embed src="<?php echo $value; ?>">
    <?php } else {
        ?>
        <p>Receipt:</p><br><img style="max-width:500px; max-height:500px;" src="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
    <?php
    }
}//added missing brace
?>
```