# pdf tag doesnt open pdf files on chrome but works on other browsers, why?

Tags: python, django

i am trying to display pdf documents on the browser but its not displaying on chrome, instead its downloading, but on other browsers like IE it's working just fine

```
{% block content_display %}

  <embed type="application/PDF" src="{{bk.upload_content.url}}" width="100%" height="650"/>

{% end block %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<embed> vs. <object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
{% block content_display %}

  <iframe src="{{bk.upload_content.url}}" width="100%" height="650"/>

{% end block %}
```

if it does not work then try this after clear your cache.

Comment: it still doesn't work, it downloads the pdf as a Type of file: file